# How do I shutdown a Wowza application from within a module?

Tags: java, wowza

I want to be able to shutdown an entire Wowza application from within a custom module, when certain configuration information is missing or incorrect. At the moment I'm forced to keep a "loaded correctly" flag, and check this before processing incoming events, but it's a very inelegant solution.

I've tried all sorts of methods I've found on appInstance / vhost / etc, but they all seem to be event handlers for override rather than API methods. I've even tried just using `System.exit()` from within `onAppStart()` but Wowza just re-starts the application and the cycle repeats.

What's the correct incantation required for a module to tell Wowza to just give up until the server has been re-started (presumably after correcting the configuration)?

Answer (score 0):

The **IApplication** interface provides a `shutdown()` [method](http://www.wowza.com/resources/serverapi/com/wowza/wms/application/IApplication.html).

You can get the appInstance in `onAppStart`:

```
 public void onAppStart(IApplicationInstance appInstance)
```

Comment: This method doesn't actually work. It will write in the logs that it's stopping the app, and deliver the onAppStop() event to the module, but proceeds to send further connect/etc events to the module.

Comment: It does work, but when a client connects a new application instance will be created automatically. That's how it works. You asked how to shutdown an app but you may be better of rejecting incoming connections on `onConnect() ` with `client.rejectConnection` if conditions are not met.